# Outlook Recipient Type based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to select the recipients email addresses (**column C**) with a fixed range *C6:C11*, based on a criteria (**MainR or CC**) defined in (**column D**) fixed range as well *D6:D11* which will then either add them as a main recipient or as a carbon copy recipient.

I have code which works with one fixed range (**column C**) *C6:C11*. For each cell in that column. It picks the cell as a recipient if the email addresses contain a **"@"** in their string.

Example below:

```
Set xRg = Sheet1.Range("C6:C11")
Set xOTApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
For Each xCell In xRg
    If xCell.Value Like "*@*" Then
        If xEmailAddr = "" Then
            xEmailAddr = xCell.Value
        Else
            xEmailAddr = xEmailAddr & ";" & xCell.Value
        End If
    End If
Next
```

I'm looking to switch the current range (**C6:C11**), with the range which contain my keywords (**D6:D11**). For every **MainR or CC** in that column, the macro should use the adjacent email address in (**column C** **C6:C11**).

The full code:

```vb
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()

'My variables

Dim xOutApp As Object
Dim xOutMail As Object
Dim xOTApp As Object
Dim xMItem As Object

Dim xMailBody As String
Dim xEmailAddr As String
Dim zEmailAddr As String

Dim xCell As Range
Dim zCell As Range
Dim xRg As Range
Dim zRg As Range


Dim ws As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next

Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)

'Email body

xMailBody = "" & vbNewLine


' Main recipient code

Set xRg = Sheet1.Range("C6:C11")

Set xOTApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
For Each xCell In xRg
    If xCell.Value Like "*@*" Then
        If xEmailAddr = "" Then
            xEmailAddr = xCell.Value
        Else
            xEmailAddr = xEmailAddr & ";" & xCell.Value
        End If
    End If
Next

' CC recipient code

Set zRg = Sheet1.Range("C7:c11")
For Each zCell In zRg
    If xCell.Value Like "*@*" Then
        If zEmailAddr = "" Then
            zEmailAddr = zCell.Value
        Else
            zEmailAddr = zEmailAddr & ";" & zCell.Value
        End If
    End If
Next

'Email Code

Set xMItem = xOTApp.CreateItem(0)
With xMItem
    .To = xEmailAddr
    .CC = zEmailAddr
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = ""
    .Body = xMailBody
    .Display   'or use .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set xOutMail = Nothing
Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image: **WORKSHEET SCREENSHOT HERE**]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your sheet? it might help to clarify the question a bit more

Comment: Hey Zac, I've added a screenshot of my sheet.

Comment: So are you just looking to apply the logic in D6:D11 range to decide if email address should be added to main or CC?

Comment: That's exactly right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve that by combining your address collection in a single `FOR` loop:

```
For Each xCell In xRg
    If xCell.Value Like "*@*" Then
        If LCase(Trim(Sheet1.Range("D"& xCell.Row).Value)) = "mainr" Then
            If xEmailAddr = "" Then
                xEmailAddr = xCell.Value
            Else
                xEmailAddr = xEmailAddr & ";" & xCell.Value
            End If
        ElseIf LCase(Trim(Sheet1.Range("D"& xCell.Row).Value)) = "cc" Then
            If zEmailAddr = "" Then
                zEmailAddr = xCell.Value
            Else
                zEmailAddr = zEmailAddr & ";" & xCell.Value
            End If
        Else
            <your error handling here for unexpected value in D range>
        End If
    End If
Next
```

As a side note, I would remove `On Error Resume Next` from the function as it tends to hide errors which is not conducive when debugging

Comment: Thanks a ton Zac, you're a champion

Comment: No worries, glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

you could use `AutoFilter()`:

```
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()

    ... your code

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xEmailAddr As String
    Dim zEmailAddr As String

    Set xRg = Sheet1.Range("C5:C11") ' include headers for autofilter to work

    With xRg.Resize(, 3) 'include email addresses and recipient columns
        .Sort key1:=.Cells(1, 3), key2:=.Cells(1, 2), header:=xlYes 'sort on recipients and email addresses to make sure you'll have adjacent filtered cells
        xEmailAddr = GetEmailAddresses(.Cells, "MainR") 'get "Main Recipient" addresses
        zEmailAddr = GetEmailAddresses(.Cells, "cc") 'get "cc" addresses
    End With

    ...
    rest of your code


End Sub

Function GetEmailAddresses(rng As Range, recipient As String) As String
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*@*" ' filter referenced cells on 1st column with "0" content
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=recipient ' filter referenced cells on 2nd column with "4000" content
        Select Case Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(3))
            Case 2
                GetEmailAddresses = .Offset(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).value
            Case Is > 2
                GetEmailAddresses = Join(Application.Transpose(.Offset(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).value), ";")
        End Select
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Function
```